# Java code optimization tips and tricks

Tags: java, performance, optimization

Specifically looking for Java code tips and tricks of the trade for:

- reducing memory footprint
- increasing performance

Personally would like to see answers focusing on the *"how"* and not the *"when"* as the consensus among savvy developers is that early optimization is a bad idea as you don't have anything to profile and thus don't know what the actual bottlenecks will be.

> "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil"
>
> "In established engineering disciplines a 12 % improvement, easily obtained, is never considered marginal and I believe the same viewpoint should prevail in software engineering"
>
> ***Donald Knuth***

Comment: Agree while this may be a good question, it is not appropriate for SO.

Comment: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Straight from http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Try posting at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: With all due respect and agreement that this question does not belong here could not we just move it to programmers instead on closing.

Comment: So this isn't appropriate, yet this is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/926266/546060 - there's tons of this stuff on SO?

Comment: That's older stuff.  Had those questions been asked now, they too would be closed.

Comment: I am going to suggest my blog because half the articles are on this topic.  There is too much to repeat http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/ I will say that most of the optimisations are for interest, as most developers would never need to worry about such low level optimisations.  If you want sub-millisecond latencies, you should find something useful.